# QString in sqlite select

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

I want to search string called x.

```
QString x=abc->text();

QSqlQuery qry("SELECT nazwa FROM piosenki WHERE nazwa like'%x%' ");
```

x is treat like a single char not like  abc->text();
 What i can do to pick QString x?
Important for me is SQlite LIKE clause becouse i want to pick from my database all similar to abc->text().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple option is to use `.arg()`

```
QString x=abc->text();
QSqlQuery query(QString("SELECT nazwa FROM piosenki WHERE nazwa like'%%1%'").arg(x));
if(query.exec()){
    int fieldNo = query.record().indexOf("nazwa");
    while (query.next()) {
        qDebug()<< query.value(fieldNo).toString();
    }
}
```

Or with `prepare()` and `bindValue()`:

```
QString x=abc->text();
QSqlQuery query;
query.prepare("SELECT nazwa FROM piosenki WHERE nazwa LIKE :nazwa");
query.bindValue(":nazwa", "%" +x + "%");
if(query.exec()){
    int fieldNo = query.record().indexOf("nazwa");
    while (query.next()) {
        qDebug()<< query.value(fieldNo).toString();
    }
}
```